# VSCode においてMarkdownファイル上でチルダを並べると謎の横線が入る

Tags: vscode, markdown

### 困りごと

VSCode で `.md` ファイルを作成します．

そして `~~ ~~` というようにチルダを４つ，間に空白を入れて書き込みます．

そうすると横線が発生します．

[image]

コードスパンに入れて分割しても横線が発生します．

[image]

ほかのMarkdownが使えるエディタ(たとえばスタックオーバーフローやHackMD)ではこんなことにならないので，不思議です．

### これまでに試したことや調べたこと

Markdownにおいて `~~` で囲うことは打消し線を意味します．

たとえば

```markdown
~~ほげほげ~~
```

はHTML でいうところの `<s>ほげほげ</s>` に相当します．

したがって `~~` で囲われた部分に横線が入るのは間違っていないのですが，コードスパンに入れてもまだ横線が入るのはおかしいです．

Markdown All in One という拡張機能を無効にすると現れなくなります．

当方のVSCodeのバージョンは下記の通りです．

> バージョン: 1.69.0 (user setup)
> コミット: 92d25e35d9bf1a6b16f7d0758f25d48ace11e5b9
> 日付: 2022-07-07T05:28:36.503Z
> Electron: 18.3.5
> Chromium: 100.0.4896.160
> Node.js: 16.13.2
> V8: 10.0.139.17-electron.0
> OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044

### 質問

この現象（コードスパンに入れても取り消し線が発生する現象）の原因はなんでしょうか？

Comment: `--disable-extensions` などで全ての拡張を無効にしても再現しますか？ また、VSCode のバージョンはいくつでしょうか。

Comment: 全部の拡張機能を無効にすると再現しませんでした．よく確かめたところ，Markdown All in One を有効にすると現れるようです．（失礼しました．質問文を修正しておきます）
また，VSCodeのバージョンも追記しておきます．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markdown All in One という拡張のバグのようです。GitHub の issue で報告されています。
[Strikethrough displays wrongly inside the editor](https://github.com/yzhang-gh/vscode-markdown/issues/974)

Answer (score 1):

VS Codeでの Markdownは, [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) のようです。
tildes (`~`) は Strikethrough (打ち消し線) に利用したり, あるいは code fenceに利用することも

参考:

- Strikethrough … [markdown-it demo](https://markdown-it.github.io/)
- Fenced code blocks … [CommonMark Spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#fenced-code-blocks)
  (markdown-it は, CommonMark spec + adds syntax extensions ＆ sugar とのこと)

---

Strikethrough を Fenced code blocks内に記述すると無効化, その他 インデントでも同様。
こちらの環境では以下の 3種類とも無効化されています。

```sh
~~Strikethrough~~
```

```
~~取り消し線~~
```

`~~` 打ち消し線 ~~

こちらの環境は以下の通り

> バージョン: 1.69.0
> コミット: 92d25e35d9bf1a6b16f7d0758f25d48ace11e5b9
> 日付: 2022-07-07T08:29:47.439Z
> Electron: 18.3.5
> Chromium: 100.0.4896.160
> Node.js: 16.13.2
> V8: 10.0.139.17-electron.0
> OS: Linux x64 5.15.0-40-generic